# Functions.php Problem

Tags: functions, theme-development

When I add lines 3 - 19 to the top of functions.php, then try to update image.php **I get the error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" when I try to update my image.php.**

The code on lines 3 - 19 creates custom next/previous links for my image gallery and redirets the last one to a "more galleries" page.

My code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/Yen04t2z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen in the pastebin the problem and merged the whole code together again. Put this first part completely into your functions.php.

```
/**
 * Display previous image link that has the same post parent.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 * Original version in /wp-include/media.php
 * @param string $size Optional, default is 'thumbnail'. Size of image, either array or string. 0 or 'none' will default to post_title or $text;
 * @param string $text Optional, default is false. If included, link will reflect $text variable.
 * @return string HTML content.
 */
function lwy_previous_image_link($size = 'thumbnail', $text = false) {
    lwy_adjacent_image_link(true, $size, $text);
}

/**
 * Display next image link that has the same post parent.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 * Original version in /wp-include/media.php
 * @param string $size Optional, default is 'thumbnail'. Size of image, either array or string. 0 or 'none' will default to post_title or $text;
 * @param string $text Optional, default is false. If included, link will reflect $text variable.
 * @return string HTML content.
 */
function lwy_next_image_link($size = 'thumbnail', $text = false) {
    lwy_adjacent_image_link(false, $size, $text);
}

/**
 * Display next or previous image link that has the same post parent.
 *
 * Retrieves the current attachment object from the $post global.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 * Original version in /wp-include/media.php
 *
 * @param bool $prev Optional. Default is true to display previous link, false for next.
 */
function lwy_adjacent_image_link($prev = true, $size = 'thumbnail', $text = false) {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    $attachments = array_values(get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->post_parent, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') ));

    foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment )
        if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
            break;

    $k = $prev ? $k - 1 : $k + 1;

    if ( isset($attachments[$k]) ) {
        $nav_link = wp_get_attachment_link($attachments[$k]->ID, $size, true, false, $text);  // save in $nav_link instead of displaying with 'echo'
    }
    // This if statement has been added
    if (empty($nav_link) || $nav_link == __('Missing Attachment')) {
        // If a new version of WP has been released, check this code snippet to behave equivalent to function wp_get_attachment_link() 
        // in post-template.php. Also the string 'Missing Attachment' has to be checked for changes.

        // $text  = $text ? esc_attr($text) : '';                   // this is simply the text which you set when calling lwy_previous_image_link() / lwy_next_image_link()
        $text = __('More Galleries', 'lwy_translate');              // display a fixed text like 'More Galleries'
        $title = __('Go to more galleries page', 'lwy_translate');  // the text which does popup when mouseover the link
        $gallery_page = '/link_to/more/galleries_page';             // !!! REPLACE WITH THE URL TO THE MORE GALLERIES PAGE !!!

        $nav_link = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a>', $gallery_page, $title, $text);
        $nav_link = apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', $nav_link, $attachments[$k]->ID, $size, true, false, $text );
    }
    echo $nav_link;
}
```

You have to replace the link in $gallery_page with the link to your more galleries page.

If you don't need translation add in image.php

```
<?php lwy_previous_image_link( false, '&larr; Previous'); ?>
<?php lwy_next_image_link( false, 'Next &rarr;'); ?>
```

You may modify the strings '← Previous' and 'Next →' as you like.

If translation should possible somewhere in the future add in image.php

```
<?php lwy_previous_image_link( false, __( '&larr; Previous' , 'lwy_translate' ) ); ?>
<?php lwy_next_image_link( false, __( 'Next &rarr;' , 'lwy_translate' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Lines 3-19 are not placed within a function, so that code is being executed when functions.php is loaded. You should put your code in a function, and call the function at the appropriate time within a template, or use your function as a callback for an action or filter.

Comment: But would that actually fix the warning i'm getting?  This is for a next/previous link in an image gallery, I assumed it is best to leave those simply in the functions.php and not necessarily in a function.

Comment: Yeah, it should. Don't echo stuff in functions.php outside of a function. That's just asking for headers already sent warnings. Output is being generated by the code at lines 3-19. This will be happening early in the flow of things.